# Convert an UWP app to Unity for the HoloLens

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens

I'm using the HoloLens and I need GPS on it. I succesfully connected my HoloLens to a Bluetooth GPS receiver and I found a project that I can use the read the GPS data in UWP ([project](https://github.com/deriven/hologps)).

I need my GPS data in Unity, so I'm trying to convert the UWP code to Unity, but Unity doesn't have for example C# StreamSockets, ... .

What is the best way to use specific UWP code in Unity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply put platform directive NETFX_CORE in your scripts:

```
#if NETFX_CORE
    using Windows.Networking.Sockets;
#endif

private void MyFunctionForHololens()
{
    #if NETFX_CORE
        // UWP code here using StreamSocket class
    #else
        // non-UWP core here (maybe some error message for platform not supported)
    #endif
}
```

Unity's platform directives documentation: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html